# Sum two different DateTime in PHP

Tags: php

My code:

```
$one = new DateTime("2018-03-15 11:53:13");
$two = new DateTime("2018-03-15 13:53:00");
$diff = $one->diff($two);
$three = new DateTime("2018-03-15 11:52:55");
$four = new DateTime("2018-03-16 11:52:57");
$difftwo = $three->diff($four);
$day = $diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
$day2 = $difftwo->format('%H:%I:%S');

$secs = strtotime($day2)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$result = date("H:i:s",strtotime($day) + $secs);

echo $result;
```

- $day = 01:59:47 

- $day2 = 00:00:02 and 1 day

Result : **01:59:49**
But I want to show : **1 01:59:49** (1 is a day result of $day2)

Can someone help me find the solution?

Comment: Please, put your code using the correct tags, do not put an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create 2 new same date. In one of them, [add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) your 2 intervals.

Then you could use the `DateInterval` object to get your value:

```
$one = new DateTime('2018-03-15 11:53:13');
$two = new DateTime('2018-03-15 13:53:00');
$diff = $one->diff($two);

$three = new DateTime('2018-03-15 11:52:55');
$four = new DateTime('2018-03-16 11:52:57');
$difftwo = $three->diff($four);

$d1 = new DateTime(); // Now
$d2 = new DateTime(); // Now
$d1->add($diff); // Add 1st interval
$d1->add($difftwo); // Add 2nd interval

// diff between d2 and d1 gives total interval
echo $d2->diff($d1)->format('%d %H:%I:%S') ;
```

Outputs :

```
1 01:59:49
```